# equivalent of parallel query of ORACLE in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there any equivalent way in mysql to run parallel query same as ORACLE

**ORACLE WAY**

```
select /*+ FULL(emp) PARALLEL(emp, 35) */
         emp_name
      from
        emp;
```

In mysql

> /*+ FULL(emp) PARALLEL(emp, 35) */

will be considered as comment

Comment: Answers on this question are on the way to become outdated as i assume MySQL 8 will be the version to get full parallel query support.. [MySQL 8.0.14: A Road to Parallel Query Execution is Wide Open!](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/23/mysql-8-0-14-a-road-to-parallel-query-execution-is-wide-open/) ... For now InnoDB only supports parallel clustered index reads meaning a (much) faster `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` is possible..

Answer (score 6):

MySQL is not Oracle (despite being owned by Oracle). It [does not support parallel queries](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1542).

You can, however, get them using [shard-query](https://code.google.com/p/shard-query/) which is a third-party database engine that supports them. See [this blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/11/15/shard-query-adds-parallelism-to-queries/) from Justin Swanhart of Percona for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `PARALLEL` keyword supported out of the box in MySQL but you can achieve it in a similar way:

```
#!/bin/bash
date
for y in {1988..2013}
do
  sql="select yeard, count(*) from ontime where yeard=$y"
  mysql -vvv ontime -e "$sql" &>par_sql1/$y.log &
done
wait
date
```

Look at the article: [Increasing slow query performance with the parallel query execution](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/07/increasing-slow-query-performance-with-parallel-query-execution/)

Comment: To be clear, this is using bash to spawn multiple MySQL processes (notice the & at the end of the mysql line). It works, but less efficient than the Oracle solution in 3 ways: (a) it's using full MySQL processes, not threads (b) it's doing the parallelism on the client side, so more communciation overhead and less chance for optimisation (c) it will often require further work, as you end up with a file with all the results combined and in arbitrary order. (Not a criticism as workarounds are unfortunately necessary when it comes to MySQL parallelism, it's just not built in.)

Comment: It will also exhaust the open connection limit for the client and the server.

Comment: Isn't this simply going to que the queries on the server anyway? I mean does this really achieve anything other than faster queuing?