# Does MySQL support parallelism while loading into a database?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I want to load data into a MySQL table using Load/Insert statement. Is there a way to use parallelism for performance benefit?

Something like this in Oracle :-

```
alter session enable parallel dml
```

P.S :- I am using `JDBC` connection for connecting to `MySQL` .

Answer (score 0):

Per this Bug thread [When will Mysql have parallel query and partitioning](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1542); there is no support for Parallel query in MySQL.

See this similar post in So [equivalent of parallel query of ORACLE in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240561/equivalent-of-parallel-query-of-oracle-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to parallel from the statements themselves, [it's more about the underlying architecture](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/scalability.html). If you are working with a cluster you can shard a database to improve performance. However, sharding is not the same as parallelizing statements in the sense of what you are asking.